# How can I expand UITableView to fill full screen on iPhone 5 using Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

Is it possible to expand a `UITableView` with static cells to adjust automatically to the 4" iPhone 5 screen and expand the height of each `UITableViewCell` accordingly? If I create a simple `UITableView` in IB with 3 static rows, when I view it on the iPhone 3.5" display it looks fine but on the iPhone 4" display there is extra whitespace at the bottom. I tried playing with autolayout (I'm only interested in iOS6), setting autosizing options, etc. but to no avail.

BTW - I know I can set the height in code e.g. in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` divide the bounds or frame height by number of rows (i.e. 3 rows). But I'm looking for something more dynamic.

[image: example of iPhone resizing issue on 3.5" and 4"]

Comment: I don't think there is any IB setting as the API already provides a dynamic method for adjusting cell height that you already seem to know: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. And anyway, what could be more dynamic than adjusting the height of the cells at run-time to the bounds of the display? This would work even for unreleased, unknown devices with both larger and smaller displays.

Comment: your tableview is loaded first, and then the cells are loaded once the dataSource methods are called.  Since cells are not loaded at the time the tableView is loaded, my guess is you cannot have a better option than "heightForRowAtIndexPath divide the bounds" way of solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys I know what your saying about the heightForRowAtIndexPath being 'dynamic'. My confusion lies with the purpose of autosizing and auto layout. Do they have any role to play here? Can they be used for the same purpose?

Comment: yes.the problem is with the autoresizing.play around with autoresizing.Just select all the sides in autoresizing option in the interface builder.That should definitely fix your issue..

Comment: I fixed this issue by setting AutoLayout (which was pretty well hidden Apple!). Once I did this everything was automatically taken care of and I have much more granular control. As I mentioned I'm only interested in iOS6 so this works for me.

Comment: @ClickAhead Please share how you have fixed the issue?So that others who may have the same problem can get some ideas.

Comment: @ClickAhead agreed with york please post your answer and mark it accepted. That way your question won't continue to show as unanswered.

Comment: Same question as Gank below, because in Xcode 6.1.1 impossible to pin UITableView from Editor > Pin with the super view. How do you please pin it using Xcode 6.1.1, a UITableView only containing static cells and Auto-Layout? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved by setting the AutoLayout property on the TableView. Once I did this the table resized accordingly. I also subsequently discover that I could do take care of resizing by setting the AutoSizing mask.

Comment: Where to set AutoLayout? I can't find it.

Comment: Same question as Gank above, because in Xcode 6.1.1 impossible to pin UITableView from Editor > Pin with the super view. How do you please pin it, using Xcode 6.1.1 and a UITableView only containing static cells? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In Xcode 6.4 I added constraints for my UITableView in the storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve (this worked for me) is to click the Apply 4-inch form factor button and extend your UITableView to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: But I can't see it on XCode 6.0 storyboard.